# How to apply permission on specific files in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and I want to develop and application to manage posts like some basic CRUD operations and so on. What i  need is a little bit of guidance on how can i add specific permission on specific post for specific users? it may sound a little confusing but i want other users not to see each other posts but only posts that the creator user allows to be seen.
I would appreciate any guidance related to this little project from database schema to its coding.

I did try a package called Spatie for laravel but i dont know whether it will fully support this scenario or not ??

Comment: specific files or posts ?

Comment: For that specific requirement [Policies and Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization) would be sufficient imho.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to give access to a specific users group for a specific posts in your database. 
If this scenario is correct then you can achieve this using your tables in database.

In order to do this you need to customize some of your tables like below:

**Step 1:**
In your posts table add an additional column called `access_level`

**Step 2:**
When the user select the post as public then add `public` keyword in that `access_level` column

**Step 3:**
When you run `select` query to show all the posts just run a `where` query like this `where access_level = "public"`

If you want to show the paticular post to a paticular user then you need to have create a table called `post_users`

- `user_id` and `post_id` are foreign keys

| id | user_id | post_id |
| 1  | 12      | 22      |
| 2  | 22      | 22      |

Comment: so we are forming a many to many relationship, thanks i will give this a try

Comment: Exactly many to many relationship, using this table you can get all the access users of a particular post or all the posts of a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use role based authentication for specific user for specific task. 
For this you can follow this git reference

[Laravel permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

```
$user->assignRole('writer');
$user->removeRole('writer');
$user->syncRoles(params);
$role->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
$role->revokePermissionTo('edit articles');
$role->syncPermissions(params);
$permission->assignRole('writer');
$permission->removeRole('writer');
$permission->syncRoles(params);
```

you can also check in brief coding [here](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-user-roles-and-permissions-acl-using-spatie-tutorialexample.html)